# Unhandled Exception: type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'M ap<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Getting below error while we are trying to run the flutter App

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'M
ap<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter ( 2949): #0      DatabaseUtils.getCloudQuestions (package:fragrancefinder/utils/DatabasUtils.dart:1282:50)
E/flutter ( 2949): <asynchronous suspension>
```

We tried running the App in Android Studio using Emulator

```
Flutter run
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to provide `Map<String, dynamic> function` but you're providing `Map<String, dynamic>` value.
If you could share some code to detect the issue.

Comment: Below is the code snippet which is throwing the error

```
static Future<List<Question>> getCloudQuestions(String local) async {
    List<Question> questions = [];
    final CollectionReference chaptersRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Locales/' + local + '/chapters');
    QuerySnapshot chaptersSnap = await chaptersRef.get();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> chaptersList = [];
    chaptersList = chaptersSnap.docs;
    for (var chapter in chaptersList) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chapterData = chapter.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: Try to change **this**  
`Map<String, dynamic> chapterData = chapter.data as Map<String, dynamic>;`  
**to this**  
`Map<String, dynamic> chapterData = chapter.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;`